# NGINX in Docker as Cache - How to keep cache on Container restart?

Tags: nginx, caching

I set up a NGINX to cache tiles coming from a OpenStreetMaps server.
My goal is to save bandwidth an have fast transfer because the OSM-server is very slooooow.

After filling up my cache with the most used tiles I lost them all after container restart.
But I want to keep the cache.

How do do this?

Here is my config:

```
proxy_cache_path  /TileCacheVol/tile levels=1:2 keys_zone=openstreetmap-backend-cache:8m max_size=500000m inactive=1000d;

proxy_temp_path   /TileCacheVol/tile/tmp;

add_header x-nginx-cache $upstream_cache_status;

upstream openstreetmap_backend {
  server  c.tile.opentopomap.org;
  server  b.tile.opentopomap.org;
  server  a.tile.opentopomap.org;
}

server {
  listen 105;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X_FORWARDED_PROTO http;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_cache openstreetmap-backend-cache;
    # Cache Dauer (2y, 365d, 4m, ...)
    proxy_cache_valid  200 302  2y;
    proxy_cache_valid  404      1m;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffer_size          128k;
    proxy_buffers              4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://openstreetmap_backend;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

I searched for a solution but did not found it. I'm no expert on this... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your question is not nginx-related.

Don't know if you really need to run nginx in Docker, but if so, you need to ensure cache persistence using Docker [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) or [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) mechanism.  In your case you need to make /TileCacheVol persistent.

Comment: Good point! Thank you!
But indeed my problem was that I messed up another .conf of my NGINX some days before. This caused the issue. Thank god i do backups.
Backup often! Backup early! :-)